GitLab SAST report - available for the next jobs
i'm tying to use this parser to get the reports from GitLab SAST and convert them in HTML.
Problem: the artifacts are only available at pipeline level (not at job level), so this means that my stage can not consume the JSON file, since it is not able to find it.
I wanted to ask if there is any workaround for this taking in account that:

I don't want to define or hard-code anything for the SAST template
I dockerized the parser, that i'm using as a Docker image in a GitLab template

Down the .gitlab-ci file and the template that i'm using:
.gitlab-ci
include:
  - template: Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
  - project: "my-templates"
    ref: main
    file:
        - "sast-parser.yml"
stages:
  - test
  - pre-job-stage
  - sast-parser

pre-job:
  stage: pre-job-stage
  extends: .collect-artifacts

sast-parser:
  stage: sast-parser
  extends: .sast-parser

sast-parser.yml
.collect-artifacts:
  image: sast-dashboard
  script:
    - mkdir artifacts
    - mv *gl-sast-report.json artifacts/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifacts/*.json

.sast-parser:
  image: sast-dashboard
  script:
    - sast-parser
    - for file in $(ls artifacts/*gl-sast-report.json); do if [ -f "$file" ]; then sast-parser "$file" > "${file%.json}.html"; else echo "$file does not exist"; exit 1; fi; done
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*.html"

